# Why would QB enterprise change from R5 to R6 cause all sdk programs to not connect?

Tags: com, qbxml

On a Windows XP system we upgraded from QB Enterprise 2014 R5 to R6 and now the external programs fail to connect.  The error message is "The procedure entry point EnumProcessModulesEx could not be located in the dynamic link library PSAPI.DLL"  Everything worked just fine on R5, but reverting back to R5 did not fix the problem.

I tried the program SDKTestPlus3.exe and when I try to connect with that I get an error: "Run-time error '-2147024769 (8007007f)'" Automation error  The specified procedure could not be found.

Searching for this error has many indications that the message is misleading and it can have something to do with 64 bit modules looking for 32 bit modules?  Not sure exactly.  Everything here should be 32 bit.

Any thoughts on what could be wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed it for my customer:
I was able to fix one of these by copying in the dll from the 2014 R4 upgrade.
I have placed it here:

http://webpages.charter.net/xenobyte/QB/QBXMLRP2.dll

1. Close QuickBooks.
2. Navigate to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intuit\QuickBooks
3. Rename QBXMLRP2.dll to QBXMLRP2.old
4. Copy in the older dll.
5. Test with SDKTestPlus3.exe or with the existing integration.

Answer (score 0):

I tested on my system (Windows 7 64-bit) using QuickBooks Enterprise Accountant 14.0 R6 and QBSDK V13. I was able to connect without a problem, and the SDKTestPlus3 application was able to connect without any errors either.

I would suggest trying a different or new company file to see if you get the same behavior. If you do get the same errors with a new company file, then I would suggest an uninstall/reinstall of both the QuickBooks Enterprise and QuickBooks SDK.

Answer (score 0):

QBXMLRP2.dll was updated in R6 and does not work with XP.

You need to revert QBXMLRP2.dll to a previous release for this to work.

Technically QB for Win XP is no longer supported, because MS is no longer supporting Win XP.

Answer (score -1):

The QBXMLRP2.DLL file is bad and needs to be updated.